# What's the difference in meaning between 1888/90 and 1888-90?

Tags: meaning, dates

When an art museum's wall text says "1888/90" does it mean that it took 2 years for the artist to make the work, or does it mean that the work was made at some point during that two-year period, but the exact year of creation cannot be ascertained? If the wall label says "1888-90" does that mean something different than 1888/90?

Comment: Ask the museum.

Comment: It may vary between country/institution/etc, so I'm reluctant to make a general statement, but for well-known artworks you should be able to find the precise history of their creation. Note that the creation of an artwork is often complex, due to interruptions, later modifications, reworking, repairs, producing copies, reproducing lost works, etc, as well as uncertainties about dates.

Comment: I'm also not sure this is a question about English language. There's not a dedicated art history SE, but History SE will look at some art questions (you can check their rules).

Comment: Such use of the slash is deplored by some, as it has more than one reading. One is 'and/or'.

Comment: The difference is that 1888-90 means 1798, whereas 1888/90 means 20.977777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777... :)

Comment: @tchrist As much as I like pedanticism, I can't get myself to upvote that comment.

Comment: In this case I don't think there's any difference, it's just the curator's style decision.

Comment: As Barmar said, this looks like a pure style choice. How is it more, please?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect 1888/90 to indicate **uncertainty within an interval**, that is, when the exact date within the interval is unknown, and 1888-90 to indicate with certainty that the work was produced **during a period**.

For example, if a sketch were made in an afternoon in a city where the artist resided for two years, but no one could document *exactly which* afternoon within the interval from 1888 to 1890, then you would want the first form to avoid misleading the reader into thinking that the sketch took two years to complete.

The international standard for writing dates and times, [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals), uses the solidus “/” to indicate time intervals. A museum might hew to this standard.

Comment: This would be a reasonable convention to adopt, but it is not the only possible one, so one cannot be certain that it has been adopted in a particular setting. For example somebody might adopt an alternative convention of writing 1888/90 to indicate a relatively continuous period and 1888-90 to indicate that the work was done on and off in these years. Or one might use 1888/90 to indicate that the work was done in either 1888 or 1890, but not 1889.

Comment: @jsw29 certainly, syntax is a fickle mistress after all, but the convention I'm using is the one that hews to an international standard

Comment: But Wikipedia has, contrastingly, 'In English, a range marked by a slash often has a separate meaning from one marked by a dash or hyphen. "[It happened sometime during the night of 24/25 December" would mark the time shared by both days (i.e., the night from Christmas Eve to Christmas morning) rather than the time made up by both days together, which would be written "24–25 December" .' Note that the first refers to a period partly overlapping both specified periods, while the second does not indicate whether 'sometime during' or 'throughout' the whole timespan is meant.

Comment: Examples like 1660/61 are often used in cases where there were different calendars in use or different possible start dates for the year depending on different (national) conventions. That wouldn't apply here though. Sometimes there may be two possible dates for an event, e.g. if two sources give different dates, or it's inferred from other things like an Olympiad or celestial event, though [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Dates_and_numbers) recommends "or" rather than "/". But the trouble with conventions is there's so many of them, all different.

Comment: I've checked the linked article, and the solidus is merely stated to be the **most usual** interval indicator. Other possibilities are mentioned.

Comment: @StuartF I think that this agrees with my suggestion that “1888/90” indicates uncertainty. I've amended my answer to make this more clear